# Issue with loading file from disk

Tags: swift, swift3, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

Ok so this one has had me scratching my head for a while.

I have a png file that I write out to disk. I get the data by:

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(scaledImage!)
let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(record.uid!).png")
```

I do a try catch and everything seems to work. The resulting filename is:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C6B796E8-2DB6-45A4-9B18-EF808B8CA3CA/Documents/580420d51800cd826a7e217c.png
```

The problem comes when I try to load that image back from the disk.

When I get a list of all files in the documents directory I get:

```
[file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C6B796E8-2DB6-45A4-9B18-EF808B8CA3CA/Documents/580420d51800cd826a7e217c.png]
```

The only difference I can see is the 'private' part of the filepath. When I try to check to see if the file exists using the filepath I get back from appending the filename (the one without the private part) I get false.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did it helped you, it worked fine in my case

Answer (score -2):

> **Swift 3/4 code**

Let us assume the method `getDocumentsDirectory()` is defined as follows

```
func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentsDirectory
}
```

In order to save the image

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(scaledImage!)
let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(record.uid!).png")
try? data?.write(to: filename)
```

And your image is saved in Documents Directory

Now in order to load it back

```
let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("\(record.uid!).png").path

let fileManager = FileManager.default
if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: imagePath){
    print("Image Present")
    //load it in some imageView
}else {
    print("No Image")
}
```

Comment: You are missing the point. Print out the urls in your code and you will see the issue: in imagePath there is no leading "private".

Comment: The OP didn't posted his `getDocumentsDirectory()` function's body so I assumed the same. My urls are:

Tested on Device--
Printing description of filename:
`"///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/46B10A6C-43EE-4D11-83E5-88B6ADF1E646/Documents/testImage.png"`

Printing description of imagePath:
`"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/46B10A6C-43EE-4D11-83E5-88B6ADF1E646/Documents/testImage.png"`

So, I believe there is some problem in `getDocumentsDirectory()` function's body which is making the url leading by private while fetching the image back. It was an assumption.